# System not booting after exhausting battery under "All UEFI" ROM launch policy

Tags: uefi, bios

I've got an HP EliteBook Folio with Windows 10. It never launched Windows, because I replaced it with Lubuntu 16.04 right away, and it performed nicely. Then it was inactive for some months, consuming all the battery. When it started again, a message showed up saying that the clock was not updated for lack of battery; that never appeared again. Then the system did not boot because the hard disk was not found, so I looked into the BIOS trying to restore factory defaults, what meant no change at all. So, I found no way for the system to recognize a USB pendrive, and install a Linux distribution again. Checked with the technical support of the shop that delivered it and they reinstalled Windows 10, allowing for a new Linux install.

My concern now is that the same situation could happen again, and I'm trying to understand how the BIOS can be configured as to avoid it. The only parameter that seems to be connected is the default UEFI policy. The entry: "Option ROM Launch Policy" allows to configure this policy, but it shows "All UEFI" by default in grey color, meaning that it cannot be changed ("All Legacy" should be an option, but won't show up). This might prevent reading the GRUB, and look for the Windows booting file (`bootmgr.exe`).

I've read somewhere that some manufacturers are trying to favor MS products, so a different OS cannot be installed; I don't know if this is the case, and how it can be avoided.

In the startup menu (pressing Esc while booting) there's this option that might be related: "3rd Party Option ROM Management", which takes me to a text-based screen headed "Drivers", with an empty "Devices List", so exit is the only available option.